# Use multiple database fields to identify users for login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm developing a RoR application with the requirement that users can log in with any of 4 possible identifiers: email, home phone #, primary phone #, or work phone #. My current solution is to use regex to see if it's a correctly formed email address, and if it isn't, to search the users table by each of the three types of phone fields in succession.

```
# did the user try to log in with an email?
if is_email params[:session][:login_param]
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:login_param].downcase)
else    # if the login parameter isn't an email...
    # try finding a user with this home number
    user = User.find_by(phone_home: params[:session][:login_param])
    if user.nil?
        # try finding a user with this cell number
        user = User.find_by(phone_cell: params[:session][:login_param])
    end
    if user.nil?
        # try finding a user with this work number
        user = User.find_by(phone_work: params[:session][:login_param])
    end
end
# verify password with user.authenticate()
```

My problem is that this has the potential to search the entire users table 3 times if a user whose record is near the end of the table tries logging in with their work number; I don't know if that will make logins too slow in production.

Is there any cleaner/faster way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you just run a query with 3 or statements. Something like select count(*) from table where (phone_home=xx or phone_cell=xx or phone_work = xx ) AND password = yy;

Comment: Steve is right, you can run one query with 4 OR conditions, do not forget to make each of these fields unique to avoid problems in future

Comment: Ooh, I hadn't thought to use raw SQL . Should I use `DB.fetch()` or would it be better to use ActiveRecord methods like `User.find(:all, :conditions => [ "(phone_home=? or phone_cell=? or phone_work = ? ) AND password == ?", :login_param, :login_param, :login_param, :password])` ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This should work as long as you validate uniqueness of the phone numbers on creation.

```
class User 
  def self.find_by_login(login)
      where("email = ? OR phone_home = ? OR phone_cell = ? OR phone_work = ?",*([login] * 4)).limit(1)
  end
end
@user = User.find_by_login(params[:session][:login_params])
#this will generate the following query with login_params = 'hello'
#=> "SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\"  WHERE (email = 'hello' OR phone_home = 'hello' OR phone_cell = 'hello' OR phone_work = 'hello')"
#authenticate @user
```

**EDIT**

As was pointed out the original version returned an array using where so I added limit(1) to return an instance of a `User`. Also as mentioned you must validate uniqueness for each of the fields to make sure it will pull the correct record.

Comment: Can you please explain the purpose of the asterisk outside of the parentheses in `*([login] * 4)`? I get that [login]*4 duplicates the login variable 4 times, but what does the extra * do?

Comment: it splits it out into individual parameters without this it will raise an exception stating `ActiveRecord::PreparedStatementInvalid: wrong number of bind variables (1 for 4)`

Comment: Should be noted that this implementation returns an array for the user variable rather than an instance of the `User` class... also by not including password in the initial find, you open yourself up to random, difficult-to-track bugs when any of the 4 login fields is duplicated by more than one user.

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 4 you can combine a `where` clause with the `find_by` method to query this for a single user:

```
login = params[:session][:login_param]
password = <however you are handling password>
User.where("email = ? OR phone_home = ? OR phone_cell = ? or phone_work = ?", login, login, login, login).find_by(encrypted_password: password)
```

This gives you the query you want:

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (email = <> OR phone_home = <> OR phone_cell = <> OR phone_work = <>) AND "users"."encrypted_password" = <> LIMIT 1
```

which will either return a user matching your criteria, or it will return `nil` if no user is found.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to engineersmnky approach, but with a few improvements:

```
class User
  # Pick the method name you prefer 
  def self.authenticate_with(login, password)
    where('(email = :login OR phone_home = :login OR phone_cell = :login OR phone_work = :login) AND password = :password', { login: login.downcase, password: password })
  end
end

@user = User.authenticate_with(params[:session][:login_params], <password>)
```

Comment: `find_by_x` methods are deprecated in Rails 4: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-record-deprecations

Comment: Yes, but why continue the convention if it has been deprecated?

Comment: @tyler find_by_x is not depreciated it is the extended dynamic finders such as find_last_by, find_all_by